# Writing to SD Card in android always returning False

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Hi guys i have to copy my sqlite db to downloads with the code bellow. But if (sd.canWrite()) always returning false... Im stuck on this , and yes im already added      to my manifest. Im debuging on real device not the virtual one. Ty for help

```
private void copyDbToExternal(Context context) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()){
            String currentDBPath = "//data//data//" + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "//databases//"
                    + "qamatrisdb";
            String backupDBPath = "qamatrisdb";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using tutorial on Dev.Android?

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Example for accessing external storage:

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has nothing to do with an SD card. Your code is writing to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

If `canWrite()` is returning `false`, you may be missing the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, or you may have `targetSdkVersion` set to 23 or higher and are not handling Android 6.0+ runtime permissions.

Also, please replace your existing `currentDBPath` logic with [a call to `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Yea sry i have to write to external storage... and i already have           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> still getting  canwrite false :(

Comment: @keikoman: Most likely, either your `<uses-permission>` element is in the wrong place, or your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html